# in rails dynamic constraints can we pass a argument to the constraint class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

in my routes.rb

```
match '/articles', :to => 'articles#index',  :constraints => UrlConstraint.new("group_articles")
```

I need to pass a "group_articles" string to compare in match method, but the above code is not calling match method of the UrlConstraint.

Also match is not accepting regex ex:'\w+/articles/?$'
Is there any other way for this to achieve?

thanks,
Sudheer.K

Answer (score 0):

1: Inside the `UrlConstraints` class you have the request object. You can use it instead of passing the `group_articles` parameter to the class.

2: In order to use constraints with regular expression:

```
get '/:id', to: 'posts#show', constraints: {id: /^\d/}
```

For example, this will pass only :id which is numeric only to posts#show.

Comment: i need to pass a string object to constraint class so that i can load the polymorphic object and set parameters.


 UrlConstraint.new("group_articles") is not calling matches method